# Aggregation of data for forecasting

Tags: forecasting, arima, aggregation

I have a univariate time series of quarterly data. I am interested in making both quarterly and yearly predictions using ARIMA/SARIMA. The quarterly prediction is just one step ahead while the yearly prediction is 1, 2 and 3 years ahead.

My question is if I should aggregated the data to annual for the annual prediction? Or should I use the quarterly data and predict 4, 8 and 12 steps ahead and then aggregate?

Comment: One option is to use Ghysels' MIDAS approach for mixed frequency econometric modeling (MIDAS stands for MIxed DAta Sampling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the quarterly data . When you go to add up the quarterly forecasts you need to take into account that the individual quarterly forecasts are correlated. This can be done with convolution using the forecast variance-covariance matrix or via montecarlo simulation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest temporial hierarchical forecasting in this case. This forecasts at every level between the input and full year and reconciles them optimally so the lower levels sum up to the higher levels. Check out the R packaged 'thief' made by Rob Hyndman. In this implementation you can choose ARIMA if you prefer that over exponential smoothing. See: http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/thief/ and https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/thief/index.html